# php - how to properly include config?

Tags: php, include, php-include

In `A.php` I include `config.php` and `B.php`:

```
include_once("path/to/config.php");
include_once("path/to/B.php");
```

`B.php` is generic script used by other scripts. I don't know if script, which included `B.php`, also included `config.php` so in `B.php` there is

```
include_once("path/to/config.php");
```

The problem is that in `A.php` I can read all the variables from `config.php`, but in `B.php` they aren't set. If I do `print_r(get_included_files())` in `B.php`, I can see that `config.php` is included.

What is causing this? How can I properly include that `config.php` so it will be available in `B.php` (and other scripts included by `A.php`...)?

EDIT: added scripts content.

`config.php`:

```
<?php

$db_ip = "";
$db_login="";
$db_pass ="";
$db_port = 30050;
$db_name_hlstats = "";
$db_name_csgo = "";
$db_name_report = "";

$db_web_host = "";
$db_web_port = "3306";
$db_web_login = "";
$db_web_pass = "";
$db_web_name = "";
```

`B.php`:

```
<?php

    function GetServers()
    {
        include_once("/data/web/virtuals/93680/virtual/config/config.php");
        include_once("/data/web/virtuals/93680/virtual/scripts/getPDO.php");
        include_once("/data/web/virtuals/93680/virtual/scripts/PDOQuery.php");

        print_r(get_included_files()); // shows config.php in included files
        echo "servers.php | $db_ip:$db_port"; // variables show nothing

        $pdo = getPDOConnection($db_ip, $db_login, $db_pass, $db_name_csgo, $db_port);

        $query = "SELECT ...";
        $result = getPDOQueryResult($pdo, $query, __FILE__, __LINE__);
        $res = array();

        foreach ($result as $row)
        {
          $res[$row["server_id"]] = $row;
        }

        return $res;
    }
```

Comment: What does `config.php` and `B.php` look like?

Comment: your paths are relative not absolute so you are not actually including the config in B you are including `path/to/path/to/config.php` which is not a file.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn: `config.php` - variables (DB hostname etc.). `B.php` - one function.

Comment: Could you please add them to your answer, It could be the way you are creating them and/or accessing them.

Comment: @cmorrissey: I always include absolute path (from the server root). In this case "/data/web/virtuals/93680/virtual/config/config.php"

Comment: @jirinovo I didn't mean add your comment to the question, I meant add the contents of the files to the question so we can see the actual code.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn: Oh yes. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason you are not getting results in `B.php` is because you are using `include_once` which will only include the file if it has not already been included. In your case you include it in `A.php` so it sees that it has already been loaded and will not load it again within `B.php` (aka it will skip the include).

If you use `include` instead within your `B.php` function you should see your results.

`require_once` and `include_once` are usually best when including libraries, that contain classes/methods/functions so you don't accidentally attempt to define them more than once.

## Examples

---

```
class MyClass{

    // Contains some methods    

}
```

When including the file doing this:

```
include 'MyClass.php';
include 'MyClass.php';
```

You will get an error saying '"MyClass" has already been defined' when it tries to load the second include.

---

When doing this:

```
include_once 'MyClass.php';
include_once 'MyClass.php';
```

PHP will skip loading the second include and you won't get an error saying that the class has already been defined.

So for you `B.php` it would be a good idea to do a `require_once` or `include_once` so you don't redefine your function and get an error.

You should also note that there are differences between `include*` and `require*`.

When using `include*` if the file couldn't be loaded the script will continue to run and depending on what you're doing could corrupt data/results.

When using `require*` if the file couldn't be loaded the script will end execution.